# Bacpac export errors

Tags: sql-server, sitecore, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I'm trying to export sitecore database to bacpac so that it can be restored to SQL Azure.

However, I'm getting error below:

One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.

```
Error SQL71564: The element Extended Property: [dbo].[Fields].[MS_DiagramPane1] is not supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file).
Error SQL71564: The element Extended Property: [dbo].[Fields].[MS_DiagramPaneCount] is not supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file).
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[ArchivedFields] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[ArchivedItems] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[Blobs] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[ClientData] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[History] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[IDTable] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[Items] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[Links] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[Notifications] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[Properties] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[PublishQueue] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[Shadows] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[SharedFields] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[Tasks] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[UnversionedFields] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[VersionedFields] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL71564: Table Table: [dbo].[WorkflowHistory] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on the errors, it looks like you're using an old version of the export tools. I would suggest installing the latest version of SSMS 2016 Preview, available from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

This version of SSMS has support for the latest Azure SQL Database V12 features.

Answer (score 2):

I added a primary key to each of these tables- fixed the errors for me
-Ronen Shemesh, crakomili.net

Comment: Fortunately it's a Sitecore CMS databases and won't be able to make changes to the schema or tables

Comment: You have to add a Clustered Index, period.  Even if it's a third-party system you can still add Clustered Index.  It has basically no impact on the  application function.